# New Controller not being located by slim framework in apache and PHP

Tags: php, apache, xampp, slim

I am trying add a new controller to an existing slim application, I have followed the same format as exists for other controllers. 
Code runs perfectly in xampp and lamp, but when I try to run it in standalone apache and PHP. I am getting Callable error, saying it is not able to find the new Controller that I defined.

The controller -

```
namespace App\Controllers;

use Respect\Validation\Validator as v;
use Slim\Http\Request;
use Slim\Http\Response;

class NewController extends Controller {
    public function addAccount(Request $request, Response $response) {

    }
}
```

Route for the controller

```
use \App\Controllers\NewController;

$app->group('/api', function(){
   $this->group('/new' , function(){
       $this->group('/account' , function() {
           $this->post('/Create', NewController::class.':addAccount');
        });

   });
});
```

Comment: Please add some details to your question and include relevant parts of code that is referred to in the question.

Comment: @Nima what would you like to see, As part of the code I have implemented the controller exactly as the working controllers. As of right now I am clueless what can be the problem. I can post whatever you need to see to may be guide me better

Comment: Including the definition of controller and also the route definition that uses that controller would probably help

Comment: @Nima I have added the Controller and the Route definition to the question